# KEY_CONFIG pointing to the wrong version of openssl.cnf

Tags: linux, openvpn, openssl

I am trying to setup OpenVPN but I am getting this error:

```
#./build-ca
grep: /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/openssl.cnf: No such file or directory
pkitool: KEY_CONFIG (set by the ./vars script) is pointing to the wrong
version of openssl.cnf: /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/openssl.cnf
The correct version should have a comment that says: easy-rsa version 2.x
```

I have OpenSSL* installed. Do I need to set a location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's hard to tell without more information...

anyhow, you have either

- not properly configured your installation via the `vars` file
- or you haven't activated the `vars` file by running `source vars` prior to running `./build-ca`

the `vars` file contains (among other things) the definition of the `KEY_CONFIG` variable. the default (on my Debian system) is to call a wrapper-script which will try to find the correct default `openssl.conf` file for you

```
export KEY_CONFIG=`$EASY_RSA/whichopensslcnf $EASY_RSA`
```

(on my system i have *OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013* installed, so KEY_CONFIG evaluates to `.../openssl-1.0.0.cnf`)

if this doesn't work for you, you can manually set the `KEY_CONFIG` to a value that matches yours.

Comment: i have the same settup, yet the whichopensslcnf points to the wrong openssl version. i have 1.1.0g installed but only 0.9.6.cnf / 0.9.8.cnf and 1.0.0.cnf.
How do i add another openssl.cnf for 1.1.0g? as source vars now gives an error the same as @frank

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer.

Comment: @BugHunterUK [citation needed]

Answer (score 48):

`ln -s openssl-1.0.0.cnf openssl.cnf`

Comment: You should explain why this command should be executed and what was the problem in the first place. Even if it may be obvious.

Comment: It's magic, but it works.

Comment: just do a ls in the folder, and you will see what openssl-x.x.x.cnf are available... 1.0.0 is the hights, ln -s is a symbolic link... guess that explains it enough?

Comment: works like magic during my setup of OpenVPN. it creates a link to the current version of openssl

Comment: symbolic link just works.

Comment: It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

By me (Debian 9.3) it works with following entrys

Insert in vars

```
export KEY_CN="xxx"
export KEY_ALTNAMES=""
```

then it works fine!